# Two inner products different by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{1}$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_{2}$ be inner product on a finite-dimensional vector space with the property that
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle_{1}=0 \Leftrightarrow \langle u,v\rangle_{2}=0
\end{align*}
for all $u,v\in V$. Show that there is a scalar $a\in F$ for which
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle_{2}=a\langle u,v\rangle_{1}
\end{align*}

I saw a solution wrote like this:

Presumably, $F=\mathbb {R}$ or $\mathbb {C}$.  For every nonzero vector $v\in V$, define $c_{v}=\frac {\langle v,v\rangle_{2}}{\langle v,v\rangle_{1}}$. Now, for any $v,w\in V$, let $x=w-\frac {\langle w,v\rangle_{1}}{\langle v,v\rangle_{1}}v$. Then $\langle x,v\rangle_{1}=0$. Hence, $\langle x,v\rangle_{2}=0$ and in turn
\begin{align*}
\langle w,v\rangle_{2}&=\frac {\langle w,v\rangle_{1}}{\langle v,v\rangle_{1}}\langle v,v\rangle_{2}\\
&=\frac {\langle v,v\rangle_{2}}{\langle v,v\rangle_{1}}\langle w,v\rangle_{1}\\
&=c_{v}\langle w,v\rangle_{1}
\end{align*}
for all nonzero $v,w\in V$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
c_{v}\langle w,v\rangle_{1}&=\langle w,v\rangle_{2}\\
&=\overline {\langle v,w\rangle_{2}}\\
&=\overline {c_{w}\langle v,w\rangle_{1}}\\
&=c_{w}\langle w,v\rangle_{1}
\end{align*}
for all $v,w\not=0$. Now, for any $v,w\not =0$, there exists some $y\in \{w+tv:t\in \mathbb {R}\}$ such that $\langle w,y\rangle_{1}$, $\langle y,v\rangle_{1}\not =0$. Hence, we have $c_{v}\langle y,v\rangle_{1}=c_{y}\langle y,v\rangle_{1}$ and $c_{y}\langle w,y\rangle_{1}=c_{w}\langle w,y\rangle_{1}$. Hence $c_{v}=c_{y}=c_{w}$ for all $v,w\not=0$. In other word, all the $c_{v}$'s are equal to some common constant $c>0$. Thus, the proof is done. But I don't know what if $\langle w,v\rangle_{1}=0$ and why do we care bout the vectors in $\{w+tv:t\in \mathbb {R}\}$.

Comment: If $\langle w,v\rangle_1=0$, then $\langle w,v\rangle_2=0$ and $0=c\times 0$ holds for any $c$, so I don't see any problem in that case.

Comment: @learner Then there's no way to find the value of c.

Comment: You don't really need to find a particular value of $c$, you have to show that there exists at least one such value that works. In the above case, any value of $c$ works, so we're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if $\langle w,v\rangle_1 = 0$?

The idea is this : if $\langle w,v\rangle \neq 0$ (and we know for sure that such $w$ exists, simply taking $w  = v$), then we can get $c_v$ from there. Now, does that $c_v$ work when $\langle w,v\rangle_1 = 0$, is the question.

But, if $\langle w,v \rangle_1 = 0$ then $\langle w,v\rangle_2 = 0$ by the given conditions, so in fact $\langle w,v\rangle_1 = c_v \langle w,v\rangle_2$ (obviously because $0 \times c_v  = 0$).

In short, it will still hold that for all non-zero $v$ and $w$ that $\langle w,v\rangle_2 = c_v \langle w,v\rangle_1$,because it will hold through the given argument if $\langle w,v\rangle_1 \neq 0$, and both sides are zero if $\langle w,v \rangle_1 = 0$.

---

> Why do we care about the vectors $w+tv$?

The best way to put it is this : if we show for any $v,w$ that $c_v = c_w$, then we are done. If $w=cv$ for some scalar $c$ then we can easily show that $c_w = c_v$.

If $w$ and $v$ are linearly independent, then consider the two dimensional subspace generated by $v$ and $w$, and restrict the inner products $1$ and $2$ to this space. The point is , that the conditions  for the inner products still hold in this two dimensional subspace. So the conclusion must hold for this subspace. Therefore, *using only the vectors in this two dimensional subspace*, we should be able to conclude that $c_v = c_w$. So we care about these vectors, because the proof should require only the properties of these vectors to conclude.

Which is why we restrict our attention to the vectors $\{w+tv : t \in \mathbb R\}$, which (up to scaling) covers every element of the span of $v$ and $w$. Then the rest should be straightforward.